# Json column returns unknown type doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have db with few columns ( sql like this):

```
`data` json DEFAULT NULL,
```

When query is run I got my db. But later query returns

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
>     Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it.

After some reading i found out that few updates are needed. I upgraded maria db to 10.2. But doctrine ORM is still 2.5 and mysql version in my wamp is lower than 5.7.8. because it seems this versions are not released yet.
How can I fix this?

Comment: The `json` data type is only available in MySQL 5.7.8+, and you can't provide a `DEFAULT` value (like with `text` types).  See: <https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html>.  It looks like the latest build of Doctine supports MySQL 5.7.9 and is aware of the `json` type (<https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/commits/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySQL57Platform.php>), so you probably just need to update your MySQL server version.

Comment: Thanks! This also helps http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295